# How do I get the line height of UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a few questions that I can't find the answers online:

1.How do I get the line height of UITextField?

2.How do I get UITextField to only enter a maximum of 3 lines of text?

3.How do I get UITextField  to only enter a maximum of 25 characters per line?

and thanks for answer!

Comment: First, "line height" is a font property, not a text field property. Second, `UITextField` is only a single line... `UITextView` is for multi-line text input. Third, do you mean max of 3 lines ***when the text wraps***? Or, 3 lines meaning max of 2 **Return** / **Newline** entries? Fourth, do you mean 25 characters per line and then ***wrap*** the text? Fifth, have you tried searching for any of these questions? Please review [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment says, you should use UITextView, not UITextField.
UITextField handles only a single line.
Use UITextView to process multiple lines of text.

I'm going to give you an opinion on number 3.

First, there is something that `limits the length` of the textview.
Auto-layout to a length of 25 characters to fit the font size you want.

The second is that when the text reaches 25 characters, `it adds a line-breaking symbol`.

```swift
extension mainVC: UITextViewDelegate {

   func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        
        if let char = text.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            let isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\\b")
            
            if isBackSpace != -92 {
                if textView.text.count == 25 {
                    textView.text += "\n"
                }
            }
        }
        
     
        return true
    }
}
```

If what you entered is `not backspace`, it will be executed. If it's 25 characters, you can add the line symbol `'\n'` to the text in textView and change it.